# Handle flex events without using a framework?

Tags: apache-flex, event-handling, event-listener

I'm developing an AIR application with Flash Builder 4 Beta 2 (nightly SDK) an am not using a framework like mate. I have a couple of views and components in my application. An outline might look like this:

```
root
|- mainview
|-- toolbar
|-- catalogue view
|--- tree
|--- datagrid
|-- statusbar
```

This is not 100% the structure of my project, but may suffice as an example. When the app get's initialized, the tree loads it's data which in my case is a list of categories. When the users clicks on an item in the tree, the data for the datagrid loads.

On every click on a tree item I dispatch an event. This event bubbles and carries the VO of the clicked item. Now I want my datagrid to catch this event. Currenty I register the event listener for this event like this (using a class and function):

```
FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.addEventListener(eventName, this.eventHandler);
```

This code is executed in the datagrid's creation complete Listener. Somehow, this seems a bit buggy to mee (altough it works). Or is it a common technic to register a component's event listener at the top level application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah this is a perfectly good solution.  Some of the frameworks add event listeners to the top most display object, like Mate and Swiz, so they can do exactly this.  Check out the [Source for Mate's GlobalDispatcher](http://code.google.com/p/mate-framework/source/browse/trunk/src/com/asfusion/mate/core/GlobalDispatcher.as) for just that.  Swiz uses something like that, plus a Cairngorm-style CentralDispatcher for non-display object global events: [Source for Swiz's CentralDispatcher](http://code.google.com/p/swizframework/source/browse/trunk/src/main/flex/org/swizframework/Swiz.as).

If you want to listen for display object events globally, registering an event listener on the top level Application is best; anything else would make it too complicated to follow.  The frameworks tend to just abstract all that away from you, through metadata (Swiz, Cairngorm 3, Parsley), and EventMaps (Mate).